# What does rotation looks like when x and y axes sits on a straight line with opposite direction.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have recently started to learn Linear Algebra and gained the intuition that 2x2 matrices can be conceptualized as the linear transformation of a 2D coordinate system from the video ["Matrix multiplication as composition | EoLA #4"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkY2DOUCWMU&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&index=4) from 3Blue1Brown.

To gain better understanding on this, I tried applying couples of combinations of linear transformation and encountered a cases which I can't understand intuitively. Here is the case:

Supposed there are 2 matrices $M_1,M_2$ representing 90 degrees rotation of the coordinate system and 90 degrees rotation of y axis ($\hat j$) respectively.
$$M_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}
,
M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
       1&-1\\
       0&0
      \end{bmatrix}$$

By applying multiplication on them with order of $M_2M_1$,I get a result of$$M_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
-1&-1\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
which seems to me indicating that the resulting transformation makes $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ pointing in the same direction which is the negative direction of axis in the original coordinate system.
My original prediction on this through drawing the coordinate transformation was $$M_3 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
1&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

[Picture of my understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8FCN.png)

In the picture linked above, my original prediction on the outcome of the process is 1,but the matrix computation provides 2.

Now ,my problem is

1.After the first transformation of rotating $\hat{j}$ for 90 degrees, how do the transformation process look like to get the correct outcome(2 in the picture)? and

2.Is it even reasonable to think of a rotation when the span of $\hat{i},\hat{j}$ has been compressed to a single straight line?

Comment: I don't think $M_2$ is what you think it is, but it is hard to tell what you want - to reverse the $y$-axis (ie reflect in the $x$-axis) you need the $-1$ in the bottom right corner, not the top right one.

Comment: The transformation I expect $M_2$ to act on the original coordinate system is to rotate $\hat{j}$ 90 degrees counterclockwise so that $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ points in a exactly opposite direction ,which makes the span of these 2 basis vectors a straight line rather than a 2d space. Did i get it wrong with the corresponding transformation of $M_2$?

Comment: I see what you are trying to do now.